# How can I implement lazy loading of data on react table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, react-table

I'm featching large amount on data and meanwhile I want to lazy load the react table

```
import React, {Component, Fragment, lazy, Suspense} from 'react'; 
const ReactTable = lazy(() => import("react-table")); 
render() 
{ 
return ( 
<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}> 
{this.state.securityCheck.length ? 
<ReactTable columns={columns} data={this.state.securityCheck} /> 
: 
<div className='text-center' style= {{fontSize: '20px'}}>No data =
Available! </div> } 
</Suspense> 
) 
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few resources for this sort of thing online, I will leave one here: https://hackernoon.com/lazy-loading-and-preloading-components-in-react-16-6-804de091c82d 

In the mean time, please update your question with any specific issues you are getting as well as your current approach.

Answer (score 2):

From the Docs:

> The fallback prop accepts any React elements that you want to render while waiting for the component to load. You can place the Suspense component anywhere above the lazy component. You can even wrap multiple lazy components with a single Suspense component.

Try this,

```
<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}> 
   <ReactTable columns={columns} data={this.state.securityCheck} /> 
</Suspense>
```

Comment: const ReactTable = lazy(() => import("react-table"));

Is this the right way to import React table for lazy load?

Comment: @ParthShrivastava Yes. It is the right way. Just make sure you are importing from correct path. For same folder we use `./filename`, for other folder we use `../foldername/filename`.